# Constructor in C# OOP

Tags: c#, oop, constructor

the constructor of this class should generate a random hint about the person that was randomly chosen, and store the hint in it's random hint property. It seems I have a problem with both my constructors but am unaware of how to fix the issue or what the issue is.. Any ideas please?

```
 class RandomHintGame : Game
    {
        string randomHint;
        static Random r = new Random();

        // Constructor 1
        public RandomHintGame(string randomHint, Person person) : base(person)
        {
            this.randomHint = randomHint;
        }
        
        // Constructor 2
        public RandomHintGame(Person person) : this(person)
        {
            int randomNumber = r.Next(0, 3);

            switch (randomNumber)
            {
                case 0: randomHint = $"The person {HasHat} a hat."; break;
                case 1: randomHint = $"The person has {EyeColor} eyes."; break;
                case 2: randomHint = $"The person is a {Gender}"; break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question to be more specific about what problems you are having. Is there some sort of error message? Or is it running but not behaving as you expect?

Comment: `public RandomHintGame(Person person) : this(person)` is definitely wrong, since there's only one single parameter constructor for this class, and it's this same one, so that'd be infinite recursion.

Comment: I need to fix both constructors as the code is wrong. I don't know what parameters to use that's what I'm asking

Comment: I need to add more parameters to the first one and the second needs to be changed

Comment: @Student: And what exactly is stopping you from doing this?

Comment: I think you just need to remove `: this(person)` from the second constructor.

Comment: I'm new to OOP and don't understand parameters or constructors very well

Comment: I tried passing randomNumber but and randomHint but it won't work

Comment: @Student: I'm afraid that "I don't know C#" isn't a very specific question.  We don't provide custom tutoring services here.  If the problem you're trying to solve is that you are new to the language and need to learn then you are encouraged to find tutorials, examples, books, courses, etc. to learn.  Practice is a good thing.  If there is a *specific* problem you're struggling to solve, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.

Comment: public RandomHintGame(Person person) : this(person)  change to  public RandomHintGame(Person person) : base(person)

Comment: Well I'm sorry my question isn't inline with your "rules" however this is a public page and asking for help isn't illegal

Comment: @Student: To learn more about this community and how we can help you, you are encouraged to start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.  If there's a specific problem you're observing with the code you have, please update the question to provide information about that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int randomNumber = r.Next(0, 3);
```

Will return 0,1,2
See [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=net-5.0#System_Random_Next_System_Int32_System_Int32_)

And your switch is for 1,2,3

And Constructor 2 base not this

```
// Constructor 2
 public RandomHintGame(Person person) : base(person)
```

Comment: Oh yes that's a mistake sorry I'll fix it

Comment: Thank you for your help. What I don't understand is how to pass the hint to the constructor

Comment: You want to Call Constructor 1 from Constructor 2 with selected hint?

Comment: The first constructor needs more parameters for the hint it should give. The second constructor needs to generate that and pass it via this(). I don't know what parameters to use. I tried passing randomNumber and randomHint

Comment: in this case you do not need to call first constructor. only need to change this to base in second constructor

Comment: So the first constructor is correct and doesn't need changing?

Comment: First constructor will create an object with given random hint and will pass person to base constructor, Second constructor will create an object and will chose random random hit and will pass person to base constructor.

Comment: Thank you that is the explanation I was looking for

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226614/discussion-between-student-and-kalvis).